# Need help making a formula look larger and nicer in latex

Tags: equations, formatting

I'm trying to make this look nicer and more readable (brackets tall enough, fraction large enough to easily read, etc).

```
$((\frac{(x(1-\delta_{1}))}{(z(1-\delta_{3}))}(1-\delta_{4}))(y(1-\delta_{2})))(1-\delta_{5})$
```

Comment: To the closers: Where is it said that the equation should fit the page?

Answer (score 2):

Such a big formula should be displayed with the `equation*` environment (or `equation` if you want it to be numbered).

Several of the brackets you use are not necessary; if you want to emphasize the factor `y(1-\delta_2)`, surround it with slightly larger parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x(1-\delta_{1})}{z(1-\delta_{3})}(1-\delta_{4})\bigl(y(1-\delta_{2})\bigr)(1-\delta_{5})
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need the nesting of brackets, which is possible with the usage of `\left` and `\right` command. `LaTeX` will check the nesting and match the bracket sizes by auto, please refer the below tag:

```
$\left(\left(\frac{(x(1-\delta_{1}))}{(z(1-\delta_{3}))}(1-\delta_{4})\right)(y(1-\delta_{2}))\right)(1-\delta_{5})$
```

and the output is look like that:

[image]

Hope this is what you expected, if not so, correct me with your exact requirement...

Comment: For this to be a good answer you should really elaborate what you did and why this improved the readability etc. (pictures may help too).

Comment: @TeXnician I have modified my post based on your suggestion, thanks...